# JavaScript if else statements to display html label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a log in form and am trying to display an error message if the log is incorrect.

For example;

If (email and password match) then set validUser to true.

> If validUser equals true then redirect to home page
>
> > Else redirect them back to log in and display one of 3 messages...

Messages are:

'Log in unsuccessful' if both email and password are incorrect

'Password incorrect' if just the password is wrong

'Email incorrect' if just the email is wrong

Is it possible to have a loop to do all this? I can't figure it out....

Trying something like this too:

```
 if (validUser==false)
{
$("message").show();
}

else if ( ..........)
{
$("passwordmessage").show();
}
```

I also want to display a message on the page and so far using this:

```
document.getElementById('message').style.display = ""
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2pkn1qrv/

So, how could I use if statements to do this and how can I correctly display a html page element using javascript or jquery?

Please ask if you need any more code or require clarification.

P.s. these are my users details

```
var USERS = {
    users: []
};

function User(type, email, password) {
    this.type = type;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

var A = new User("rep", "a@a.com", "a");
USERS.users.push(A);

var B = new User("rep", "b@b.com", "b");
USERS.users.push(B);

var C = new User("customer", "c@c.com", "c");
USERS.users.push(C);

var D = new User("grower", "d@d.com", "d");
USERS.users.push(D);

module.exports = USERS;
```

Comment: You return the full list of users and passwords on the client?

Comment: if/else are not “loops”.

Comment: I wouldn't redirect the user anyplace on a failed login.  You should just display a message that the login failed.  ie. Incorrect user and/or password.  You want to avoid giving away too much information about the failure pertaining to login.  You are allowing someone to gain more information about the system with each attempt.  I can brute-force a valid user and then begin to work on the password according to your logic.  You should create the "authentication" as a separate function and return true or false.  Then depending on the result handle the message to the user or redirect in the sys.

Comment: @epascarello I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @CBroe sorry didn't realize that when I was submitting the question. It is a statement right?

Comment: @eyegropram ok, thanks for the heads up. I'll definitely have a look in to this. For now I am creating a simple working prototype to display my skills learnt and have been advised to display messages depending on what failed, to show I understand how to do it, hence my reasoning for printing a message for each field. I will definitely consider changing this though at the end should I continue with development.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be having 3 conditions in that case. you will check email availability and password match. If anyone fails, you can display the message. I couldnt test your code but this will be the logic and i assume Users.user[x].email is the list of emails from your database. If yes, sorry to say that its a bad practise.

```
  validUser = false;
  emailAvailable = false;
  passwordIncorrect = false;
    for (var x in USERS.users) {
         if(!emailAvailable && emailLog === USERS.users[x].email){
                 emailAvailable = true;
           } //Checks whether email is available.
         if(emailAvailable && passwordLog === USERS.users[x].password){
                 passwordIncorrect = true;
                 break;
           } //Checks whether the password is correct for that email.


    } // end of for



     if(!emailAvailable){
    console.log("Email is incorrect");
   }
       else if(emailAvailable && !passwordIncorrect){
console.log("Password is incorrect");}
        else{
             validUser = true;
             console.log("Valid User");
}

if(validUser){
//redirect
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes my issue much clearer so hopefully I will be able to implement this correctly. How would you go about accessing the email from the data array? I couldn't find another way which worked for me other than the USERS.users[x].email

Comment: Please mark my answer as useful if  you find this useful.Thanks for confirming back.

Comment: I got this to work and print to the console but how can I print the output message to the web page?

Comment: remove the console and use this page to guide you to print the message in webpage.http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think my way is it worth to give a try:

First: create a Javascriptobject:

```
 function ruleToCheck(errorRule, errorMsgContainer)
 {
  this.errorCondition = errorRule;
  this.errorMessage = errorMsgContainer;
 }
```

after that create an array and fill it with your rules:

```
 var rulesList = new Array();
 rulesList.push(new ruleToCheck("validUser === true", "message"));
 ...
```

Then loop through the array:

```
 var rulesListLength = rulesList.length;
 var index = 0;
 while (index < rulesListLength)
 {
   index++;
   ...
 }
```

The secret of success is the powerful `eval()` function within the `while()` loop:

```
 if (eval(rulesList[index].errorCondition))
 {
     $("#"+rulesList[index].errorMessage).show();
     break;
     //If 'break does not work, use 'index = rulesListLength'
 }
```

Hope it was helpful or at least leaded you into the right direction.
By the way, take care of the comments on your question.